# all coefficients turn zero in Logistic regression using scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am working on logistic regression using scikit learn in python.
I have the data file that can be downloaded via the following link.

[link for data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DNLuOQUgk8v4184wtnFDuaEmUs3s5ZfK)

Below is my code for machine learning part.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import pandas as pd
scaler = StandardScaler()

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataX = data.drop('outcome',axis =1).values.astype(float)
X     = scaler.fit_transform(dataX)
dataY = data[['outcome']]
Y = dataY.values

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split (X,Y,test_size = 0.25, random_state = 33)
lasso = Lasso(alpha=.3)
lasso.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("MC learning completed")
print(lasso.score(X_train,y_train))
print(lasso.score(X_test,y_test))
print(lasso.coef_)
```

when I print coefficients, it turns out all zero.
Can anyone advise me on that?

Let me explain a little bit about my objective. The problem seems to be a classification problem as we can only see 0 or 1 in Ytrain and Ytest. if we put a simple example, 0 can be considered as **missed**, 1 can be considered as **scored**. what I am trying to do is to compute the probability scoring  for each event when a shot is taken place.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Zep

Comment: Hi Kumar,
Thanks for the reply. I attached the data file as well. just click on the link to download it.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I omitted that part.

Comment: no problem. appreciate your help.thanks

Comment: I'm seeing a Lasso model being used instead of a logistic regression. Lasso is used for regression rather than classification.

Comment: Hi Kumar,
I am working on regression not for classification.
using the coefficients, i could be able to predict the probability of outcome.
Thanks

Comment: @Zephyr Lasso would still be inappropriate. If you want to predict the probability, Logistic Regression has a [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba) function. Predictions from your Lasso won't always guarantee the predictions will be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks @Scratch'N'Purr.
i will use as suggested.

Comment: @Zephyr I just modified my answer showing how to perform a GridSearch to find the best `alpha` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Y` variable contains only `0`s and `1`s. If you still want to apply regression on this data then use a GridSearch for different alpha parameters.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import pandas as pd
scaler = StandardScaler()

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataX = data.drop('outcome',axis =1).values.astype(float)
X     = scaler.fit_transform(dataX)
dataY = data[['outcome']]
Y = dataY.values

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split (X,Y,test_size = 0.25, random_state = 33)
lasso = Lasso(alpha=.0009)
lasso.fit(X_train,y_train)
print("MC learning completed")
print(lasso.score(X_train,y_train))
print(lasso.score(X_test,y_test))
print(lasso.coef_)
```

---

**Results**

```
MC learning completed
0.37884924358295613
0.3806187071242917
[ 0.00078099  0.13397938 -0.00554932  0.00194722  0.00232949 -0.01100195
 -0.01363906  0.13031317 -0.00146605]
```

---

**GridSearchCV**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import numpy as np

# Define the grid for the alpha parameter
parameters = {'alpha':[0.01, 0.001, 0.0005]}

# Fit it on X, Y and define the cv parameter for cross-validation
clf = GridSearchCV(lasso, parameters, cv = 3)
clf.fit(X, Y)

# Get the best parameters and model
print(clf.best_estimator_)
```

**Note**: To define a specific parameter space use: `parameters = {'alpha': np.arange(0.001,1,0.02)}`

---

### **EDIT 1:** After taking into account the last paragraph that you just added in your question, use this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import pandas as pd
scaler = StandardScaler()

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
dataX = data.drop('outcome',axis =1).values.astype(float)
X     = scaler.fit_transform(dataX)
dataY = data[['outcome']]
Y = dataY.values

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split (X,Y,test_size = 0.25, random_state = 33)

# Logistic Regression (aka logit, MaxEnt) classifier.
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train,y_train)

# Predict the probability of the testing samples to belong to 0 or 1 class
predicted_probs = lr.predict_proba(X_test)
print(predicted_probs[0:3])

# The proba of the first testing sample to belong to class 0 is 0.8704 and to class 1 0.1295
[[0.87046267 0.12953733]
 [0.87797594 0.12202406]
 [0.80046704 0.19953296]]
```

Comment: Thanks @seralouk.

Comment: Hope this helps. See also my last comment at the end of my answer. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @seralouk. How could i check the accuracy of the fit. I am new to machine learning.

Comment: What exactly do you want to compute ? Accuracy usually refers to classification evaluation but here you have a regression problem. Maybe MSE or MAE ? Let me know and I can help you with all these

Comment: I used lasso to predict the probability of outcome. So i will use all coefficients to compute that probability. thanks

Comment: @Zephyr see EDIT 1 in my answer and consider upvoting my answer

Comment: Thanks @seralouk. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just change alpha in Lasso :
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hReDi.png)

Comment: Thanks @chuzz.
How could I check the accuracy of the model?

Answer (score 0):

The data in Y looks like classes. They are either 0 or 1. So you should use classification algorithms and then use the coeff to get the probability.

Most scikit classifiers have a `predict_proba()` which you can use the get the probability directly.

If there is a need to absolutely use the regression models, then you can try [LinearRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) which will use Ordinary least squares method, or [`LassoCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoLarsCV.html) which will automatically tune the alphas to suit the need.